# How can I get the HEX code for CSS parsed using ExCSS

Tags: css, .net, excss

I'm using https://github.com/HockeyJustin/ExCSS_Core (an update of ExCSS to support .NET4) to parse a CSS file with the aim of extracting the relevant sections of selectors that contain colour references in their definitions, be they #, rgb or rgba.

e.g.

```
.selector {
   border: 1px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

gets returned as

```
.selector {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

I've managed this fine, but try as I might the *hex* codes are all being converted into *rgb*, giving

```
.selector {
   background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
}
```

Does anyone please know of a method of returning the colour codes in their original format?

Alternatively, is there a better way of achieving this?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, using ExCSS and needing to get the color style (`rgb(0,0,0)`) into a usable format. We ended up with a custom method to try to convert HTML / CSS colors into [`System.Drawing.Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color). The below handles some other cases which we need like `#000000` and `blue` as colors, but also the `rgb(0,0,0)` as mentioned in the question above. No guarantees this is up to spec, but seems adequate for our needs (TODO: refactor `FromHtmlHexUnverified` into the main method).

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// Attempts to parse a color described by a CSS style to a standard color object.
/// This will first attempt to parse as a color with a leading "#".
/// If that fails, will check if this is a "rgb(0,0,0)" formatted string.
/// If that fails, will attempt to lookup the value according to standard
/// color definition names ("black", etc).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">CSS style color value.</param>
/// <returns>Parsed color.</returns>
public static Color FromCss(string value)
{
    var trimmed = value?.Trim() ?? null;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed))
    {
        // check on trimmed, but throw against value
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(value));
    }

    int r, g, b;

    // try leading hash color
    if (trimmed[0] == '#')
    {
        if (trimmed.Length == 4)
        {
            // one digit hex values
            r = Convert.ToInt32(trimmed.Substring(1, 1), 16);
            g = Convert.ToInt32(trimmed.Substring(2, 1), 16);
            b = Convert.ToInt32(trimmed.Substring(3, 1), 16);
        }
        else if (trimmed.Length == 7)
        {
            // two digit hex values
            r = Convert.ToInt32(trimmed.Substring(1, 2), 16);
            g = Convert.ToInt32(trimmed.Substring(3, 2), 16);
            b = Convert.ToInt32(trimmed.Substring(5, 2), 16);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(value));
        }

        var color = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
        return color;
    }
    // try rgb(0,0,0) color
    else if (trimmed.StartsWith("rgb"))
    {
        int start = trimmed.IndexOf('(') + 1;
        int end = trimmed.IndexOf(')');

        if (!(start > 0) || !(end > -1) || (end <= start))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(value));
        }

        var inner = trimmed.Substring(start, end - start);
        var values = inner.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
        if (!values.Any() || values.Count != 3)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(value));
        }

        // RGB values are decimal
        r = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
        g = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
        b = Convert.ToInt32(values[2]);

        var color = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
        return color;
    }
    // try standard name color
    else
    {
        switch (trimmed.ToLower())
        {
            /*
             * These are "standard"? CSS colors
             */
            case "aliceblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f0f8ff");
            case "antiquewhite": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#faebd7");
            case "aqua": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#00ffff");
            case "aquamarine": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#7fffd4");
            case "azure": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f0ffff");
            case "beige": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f5f5dc");
            case "bisque": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffe4c4");
            case "black": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#000000");
            case "blanchedalmond": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffebcd");
            case "blue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#0000ff");
            case "blueviolet": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#8a2be2");
            case "brown": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#a52a2a");
            case "burlywood": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#deb887");
            case "cadetblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#5f9ea0");
            case "chartreuse": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#7fff00");
            case "chocolate": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#d2691e");
            case "coral": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ff7f50");
            case "cornflowerblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#6495ed");
            case "cornsilk": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#fff8dc");
            case "crimson": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#dc143c");
            case "cyan": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#00ffff");
            case "darkblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#00008b");
            case "darkcyan": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#008b8b");
            case "darkgoldenrod": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#b8860b");
            case "darkgray": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#a9a9a9");
            case "darkgrey": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#a9a9a9");
            case "darkgreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#006400");
            case "darkkhaki": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#bdb76b");
            case "darkmagenta": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#8b008b");
            case "darkolivegreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#556b2f");
            case "darkorange": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ff8c00");
            case "darkorchid": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#9932cc");
            case "darkred": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#8b0000");
            case "darksalmon": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#e9967a");
            case "darkseagreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#8fbc8f");
            case "darkslateblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#483d8b");
            case "darkslategray": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#2f4f4f");
            case "darkslategrey": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#2f4f4f");
            case "darkturquoise": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#00ced1");
            case "darkviolet": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#9400d3");
            case "deeppink": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ff1493");
            case "deepskyblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#00bfff");
            case "dimgray": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#696969");
            case "dimgrey": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#696969");
            case "dodgerblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#1e90ff");
            case "firebrick": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#b22222");
            case "floralwhite": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#fffaf0");
            case "forestgreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#228b22");
            case "fuchsia": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ff00ff");
            case "gainsboro": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#dcdcdc");
            case "ghostwhite": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f8f8ff");
            case "gold": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffd700");
            case "goldenrod": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#daa520");
            case "gray": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#808080");
            case "grey": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#808080");
            case "green": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#008000");
            case "greenyellow": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#adff2f");
            case "honeydew": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f0fff0");
            case "hotpink": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ff69b4");
            case "indianred": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#cd5c5c");
            case "indigo": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#4b0082");
            case "ivory": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#fffff0");
            case "khaki": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f0e68c");
            case "lavender": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#e6e6fa");
            case "lavenderblush": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#fff0f5");
            case "lawngreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#7cfc00");
            case "lemonchiffon": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#fffacd");
            case "lightblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#add8e6");
            case "lightcoral": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f08080");
            case "lightcyan": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#e0ffff");
            case "lightgoldenrodyellow": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#fafad2");
            case "lightgray": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#d3d3d3");
            case "lightgrey": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#d3d3d3");
            case "lightgreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#90ee90");
            case "lightpink": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffb6c1");
            case "lightsalmon": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffa07a");
            case "lightseagreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#20b2aa");
            case "lightskyblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#87cefa");
            case "lightslategray": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#778899");
            case "lightslategrey": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#778899");
            case "lightsteelblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#b0c4de");
            case "lightyellow": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffffe0");
            case "lime": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#00ff00");
            case "limegreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#32cd32");
            case "linen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#faf0e6");
            case "magenta": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ff00ff");
            case "maroon": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#800000");
            case "mediumaquamarine": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#66cdaa");
            case "mediumblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#0000cd");
            case "mediumorchid": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ba55d3");
            case "mediumpurple": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#9370d8");
            case "mediumseagreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#3cb371");
            case "mediumslateblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#7b68ee");
            case "mediumspringgreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#00fa9a");
            case "mediumturquoise": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#48d1cc");
            case "mediumvioletred": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#c71585");
            case "midnightblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#191970");
            case "mintcream": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f5fffa");
            case "mistyrose": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffe4e1");
            case "moccasin": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffe4b5");
            case "navajowhite": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffdead");
            case "navy": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#000080");
            case "oldlace": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#fdf5e6");
            case "olive": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#808000");
            case "olivedrab": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#6b8e23");
            case "orange": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffa500");
            case "orangered": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ff4500");
            case "orchid": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#da70d6");
            case "palegoldenrod": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#eee8aa");
            case "palegreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#98fb98");
            case "paleturquoise": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#afeeee");
            case "palevioletred": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#d87093");
            case "papayawhip": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffefd5");
            case "peachpuff": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffdab9");
            case "peru": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#cd853f");
            case "pink": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffc0cb");
            case "plum": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#dda0dd");
            case "powderblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#b0e0e6");
            case "purple": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#800080");
            case "red": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ff0000");
            case "rosybrown": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#bc8f8f");
            case "royalblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#4169e1");
            case "saddlebrown": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#8b4513");
            case "salmon": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#fa8072");
            case "sandybrown": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f4a460");
            case "seagreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#2e8b57");
            case "seashell": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#fff5ee");
            case "sienna": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#a0522d");
            case "silver": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#c0c0c0");
            case "skyblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#87ceeb");
            case "slateblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#6a5acd");
            case "slategray": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#708090");
            case "slategrey": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#708090");
            case "snow": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#fffafa");
            case "springgreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#00ff7f");
            case "steelblue": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#4682b4");
            case "tan": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#d2b48c");
            case "teal": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#008080");
            case "thistle": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#d8bfd8");
            case "tomato": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ff6347");
            case "turquoise": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#40e0d0");
            case "violet": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ee82ee");
            case "wheat": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f5deb3");
            case "white": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffffff");
            case "whitesmoke": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#f5f5f5");
            case "yellow": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#ffff00");
            case "yellowgreen": return FromHtmlHexUnverified("#9acd32");

            default: throw new NotSupportedException($"Can not resolve CSS color: {trimmed}");
        }
    }
}

// convert without safety checks
private static Color FromHtmlHexUnverified(string value)
{
    int r, g, b;
    r = Convert.ToInt32(value.Substring(1, 2), 16);
    g = Convert.ToInt32(value.Substring(3, 2), 16);
    b = Convert.ToInt32(value.Substring(5, 2), 16);
    var color = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
    return color;
}
```